# Getting message error PHP: Trying to get property of non-object when trying to print my data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got some error when I am trying to print my data from my table using DOMPDF in Codeigniter. See my picture [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZNq8.jpg)

> A PHP Error was encountered 
>   Severity: Notice 
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object 
>   Filename: views/print-pasien.php 
>   Line Number: 57

and other lines number on my print-pasien views as well.

Well, this is my following code :

**Controller**

```
public function cetak_pasien(){

    $data['pasien'] = $this->a_model->view();
    $this->load->view('print-pasien', $data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("print-pasien" . ".pdf", array ('Attachment' => 0));
}
```

**Model**

```
public function view(){
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT kode_pasien,nama_pasien, email_pasien, alamat_pasien, tanggal_lahir,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,tanggal_lahir,CURDATE()) AS umur, jenis_kelamin, no_telp FROM tb_pasien");
   return $query;

}
```

**View**

```
<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Kode Pasien</th>
                    <th>Nama Pasien</th>        
                    <th>Email Pasien</th>
                    <th>Alamat Pasien</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                    <th>Umur</th>
                    <th>JK</th>
                    <th>No. Telp</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                if( ! empty($pasien)){
                    $no = 1;
                    foreach($pasien as $data){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$no."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$data->kode_pasien."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->nama_pasien."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->email_pasien."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->alamat_pasien."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->tanggal_lahir."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->umur."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->jenis_kelamin."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "<td>".$data->no_telp."</td>"; //here my problem
                    echo "</tr>";
                    $no++;
                    }
                }
                ?>
                </table>
```

PS: I didnt hold any data of 'umur' field on my database table, I only call it by using SQL statement on my model.

Comment: I bet you've never even tried to Google that error before posting this. Am I right?

Comment: so `$data` is not an object. you need to do `var_dump($data)` to see what it is. maybe it's an array, not an object.

Comment: i tried it though, i also try to search here on stackoverflow but I just cant understand , sorry I am still newbie using Codeigniter @AlonEitan

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter you will get an array of objects or a pure array depending if you are using $query->result() or $query->result_array() respectively.  If you are using $query->row() the result will be returned as an object.

What I see here is that you are not using any of these.  Instead you are returning *$query* directly which will give you a **CI_DB_mysqli_result Object**.

Try these lines on your controller printing directly without calling your view:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

I think you'll see something like:

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => mysqli Object
        (
            [affected_rows] => 13
            [client_info] => 5.5.19...
```

Now go to your model and change **return $query;** to **return $query->result();** and see what prints now.  Probably something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
```

With this you now have an Array of objects.  My trick when I hit a wall is to first *print_r* on the model, then the controller and finally on the view just to make sure my data arrived and how it is organised before assuming everything came exactly as I expected.